# "lose out" or "lose"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I don't get the meaning of phrasal verb "lose out". Lets consider this example:

> The deal will ensure that shareholders do not lose/ lose out financially.

In this context are they have any difference?

Or can I at least freely use lose instead of lose out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Lose out" is a little different than "lose". "Lose out" includes the sense that you were placed at a disadvantage or lost an opportunity.

"The deal will ensure that the shareholders don't lose financially" means that without the deal, the shareholders will lose money.

"The deal will ensure that the shareholders don't lose out" means that the shareholders have an opportunity to make more money, and this deal will ensure that they don't miss that opportunity.